# How to display multiple messages on javascript scroller?

Tags: javascript, arrays, scroll

I am new to javascript and have to maintain an old application. I would like to know if there is a way I can make this scroller display more than one message at a time. 
Thanks.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" bordercolor="#EAFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" background="http://www.cosco-usa.com/images/td_bg.gif " style="width: 21%">
  <a href="http://www.coscoamericas.com/channels/176.html" title="More News" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://www.cosco-usa.com/images/newspaper.ico" align="absmiddle" alt="" border="0"></a>
      <img src="http://www.cosco-usa.com/images/px1.gif" width="6" height="1" alt="" border="0">              <a href="http://www.coscoamericas.com/channels/176.html" title="More News" target="_blank">
  <font face="Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular" size="2"><b>LATEST NEWS</b></font></a>
      <img src="http://www.cosco-usa.com/images/px1.gif" width="20" height="1" alt="" border="0">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

There is an array messages[] that holds all the messages.

```js
var scrollerdelay='3000' //delay between msg scrolls. 3000=3 seconds.
var scrollerwidth='220px'
var scrollerheight='60px'
var scrollerbgcolor='E6E6E6'
//set below to '' if you don't wish to use a background image
var scrollerbackground='paper1.jpg'

//configure the below variable to change the contents of the scroller
var messages=new Array()

messages[0]="<font face='Verdana' size='-1' color='teal'><a href='http://www.coscoamericas.com/contents/176/538.html'>Message 1!</a></font>"
messages[1]="<font face='Verdana' size='-1' color='teal'><a href='http://www.coscoamericas.com/contents/176/538.html'>Message 2!</a></font>"
messages[2]="<font face='Verdana' size='-1' color='teal'><a href='http://www.coscoamericas.com/contents/176/538.html'>Message 3!</a></font>"
messages[3]="<font face='Verdana' size='-1' color='teal'><a href='http://www.coscoamericas.com/contents/176/538.html'>Message 4!</a></font>"
messages[4]="<font face='Verdana' size='-1' color='teal'><a href='http://www.coscoamericas.com/contents/176/538.html'>Message 5!</a></font>"
```

**JavaScript** -

```
var ie = document.all
var dom = document.getElementById

if (messages.length > 2)
    i = 2
else
    i = 0

function move1(whichlayer) {
    tlayer = eval(whichlayer)
    if (tlayer.top > 0 && tlayer.top <= 5) {
        tlayer.top = 0
        setTimeout("move1(tlayer)", scrollerdelay)
        setTimeout("move2(document.main.document.second)", scrollerdelay)
        return
    }
    if (tlayer.top >= tlayer.document.height * -1) {
        tlayer.top -= 5
        setTimeout("move1(tlayer)", 50)
    } else {
        tlayer.top = parseInt(scrollerheight)
        tlayer.document.write(messages[i])
        tlayer.document.close()
        if (i == messages.length - 1)
            i = 0
        else
            i++
    }
}

function move2(whichlayer) {
    tlayer2 = eval(whichlayer)
    if (tlayer2.top > 0 && tlayer2.top <= 5) {
        tlayer2.top = 0
        setTimeout("move2(tlayer2)", scrollerdelay)
        setTimeout("move1(document.main.document.first)", scrollerdelay)
        return
    }
    if (tlayer2.top >= tlayer2.document.height * -1) {
        tlayer2.top -= 5
        setTimeout("move2(tlayer2)", 50)
    } else {
        tlayer2.top = parseInt(scrollerheight)
        tlayer2.document.write(messages[i])
        tlayer2.document.close()
        if (i == messages.length - 1)
            i = 0
        else
            i++
    }
}

function move3(whichdiv) {
    tdiv = eval(whichdiv)
    if (parseInt(tdiv.style.top) > 0 && parseInt(tdiv.style.top) <= 5) {
        tdiv.style.top = 0 + "px"
        setTimeout("move3(tdiv)", scrollerdelay)
        setTimeout("move4(second2_obj)", scrollerdelay)
        return
    }
    if (parseInt(tdiv.style.top) >= tdiv.offsetHeight * -1) {
        tdiv.style.top = parseInt(tdiv.style.top) - 5 + "px"
        setTimeout("move3(tdiv)", 50)
    } else {
        tdiv.style.top = parseInt(scrollerheight)
        tdiv.innerHTML = messages[i]
        if (i == messages.length - 1)
            i = 0
        else
            i++
    }
}

function move4(whichdiv) {
    tdiv2 = eval(whichdiv)
    if (parseInt(tdiv2.style.top) > 0 && parseInt(tdiv2.style.top) <= 5) {
        tdiv2.style.top = 0 + "px"
        setTimeout("move4(tdiv2)", scrollerdelay)
        setTimeout("move3(first2_obj)", scrollerdelay)
        return
    }
    if (parseInt(tdiv2.style.top) >= tdiv2.offsetHeight * -1) {
        tdiv2.style.top = parseInt(tdiv2.style.top) - 5 + "px"
        setTimeout("move4(second2_obj)", 50)
    } else {
        tdiv2.style.top = parseInt(scrollerheight)
        tdiv2.innerHTML = messages[i]
        if (i == messages.length - 1)
            i = 0
        else
            i++
    }
}

function startscroll() {
    if (ie || dom) {
        first2_obj = ie ? first2 : document.getElementById("first2")
        second2_obj = ie ? second2 : document.getElementById("second2")
        move3(first2_obj)
        second2_obj.style.top = scrollerheight
        second2_obj.style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else if (document.layers) {
        document.main.visibility = 'show'
        move1(document.main.document.first)
        document.main.document.second.top = parseInt(scrollerheight) + 5
        document.main.document.second.visibility = 'show'
    }
}

window.onload = startscroll;

<ilayer id="main" width=&{scrollerwidth}; height=&{scrollerheight}; bgColor=&{scrollerbgcolor}; background={scrollerbackground}; visibility=hide>
    <layer id="first" left=0 top=1 width=&{scrollerwidth};>
        <script language="JavaScript1.2">
            if (document.layers)
                document.write(messages[0])
        </script>
    </layer>
    <layer id="second" left=0 top=0 width=&{scrollerwidth}; visibility=hide>
        <script language="JavaScript1.2">
            if (document.layers)
                document.write(messages[dyndetermine=(messages.length==1)? 0 : 1])
        </script>
    </layer>
</ilayer>

<script language="JavaScript1.2">
    if (ie || dom) {
        document.writeln('<div id="main2" style="position:relative;width:' + scrollerwidth + ';height:' + scrollerheight + ';overflow:hidden;background-color:' + scrollerbgcolor + ' ;background-image:url(' + scrollerbackground + ')">')
        document.writeln('<div style="position:absolute;width:' + scrollerwidth + ';height:' + scrollerheight + ';clip:rect(0 ' + scrollerwidth + ' ' + scrollerheight + ' 0);left:0px;top:0px">')
        document.writeln('<div id="first2" style="position:absolute;width:' + scrollerwidth + ';left:0px;top:1px;">')
        document.write(messages[0])
        document.writeln('</div>')
        document.writeln('<div id="second2" style="position:absolute;width:' + scrollerwidth + ';left:0px;top:0px;visibility:hidden">')
        document.write(messages[dyndetermine = (messages.length == 1) ? 0 : 1])
        document.writeln('</div>')
        document.writeln('</div>')
        document.writeln('</div>')
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: The code you provided doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: please update your post with rendered HTML. It's hard to predict / debug the actual issue.

Comment: I have added the html and the missing portion of javascript that stores messages in an array. Any help on this will be appreciated.Thanks.